# How to fetch data from self reference entity in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have two tables:

1. medicaments_group
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0Bnn.png)
2. medicaments_group_join
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sCXd.png)

There is my Entity class:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "medicaments_group") @Getter @Setter public class MedicamentGroup extends GenericDictionary {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private boolean groupMain;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "medicaments_group_join",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "medicament_group_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "medicament_join_id")
    )
    private List<MedicamentGroup> childrens = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "medicaments_group_join",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "medicament_join_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "medicament_group_id")
    )
    private List<MedicamentGroup> childrenOf; }
```

And i would like to return List of MedicamentGroup with List of its children, so i wrote query like that:

> ```
> @Override
> public List<MedicamentGroup> getGroupsAndItsChildren() {
>     List<Tuple> query = Objects.requireNonNull(getQuerydsl())
>             .createQuery()
>             .from(medicamentGroup)
>             .select(id, shortName, childrens)
>             .where(groupMain.isFalse())
>             .fetch();
>
>
>
>     return query.stream().map(tuple -> {
>         MedicamentGroup group = new MedicamentGroup();
>         group.setId(tuple.get(id));
>         group.setShortName(tuple.get(shortName));
>         group.setChildrens(tuple.get(childrens));
>         return group;
>     }).toList();
> }
> ```

And now, when i try to call this method from my repository layer i got an error:

> Hibernate: select medicament0_.id as col_0_0_, medicament0_.short_name
> as col_1_0_, . as col_2_0_, medicament2_.id as id1_20_,
> medicament2_.active as active2_20_, medicament2_.name as name3_20_,
> medicament2_.short_name as short_na4_20_, medicament2_.group_main as
> group_ma5_20_ from medicaments_group medicament0_ inner join
> medicaments_group_join childrens1_ on
> medicament0_.id=childrens1_.medicament_group_id inner join
> medicaments_group medicament2_ on
> childrens1_.medicament_join_id=medicament2_.id where
> medicament0_.group_main=? 2023-04-03 20:12:23.563  WARN 46674 ---
> [nio-8089-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL
> Error: 0, SQLState: 42601 2023-04-03 20:12:23.563 ERROR 46674 ---
> [nio-8089-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR:
> syntax error at or near "."   Position: 74 2023-04-03 20:12:23.579
> ERROR 46674 --- [nio-8089-exec-3] p.k.c.w.f.ErrorResponseFactoryImpl
> : Error response
>
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
> not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
> ResultSet     at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)
> ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]   at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
> ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]   at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
> ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]   at
> org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
> ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]    at
> org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
> ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]    at
> org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
> ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]    at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

So could you help me and tell me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score -1):

In your entity class do the mapping like this:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "medicaments_group") @Getter @Setter public class MedicamentGroup extends GenericDictionary {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private boolean groupMain;

     @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<MedicamentGroup> childrens = new ArrayList<>();

     @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<MedicamentGroup> childrenOf; }
```

Also, try deleting the database and then creating a new database. It often works.

Comment: There is not a good solution. With that I am unable to run the application

Comment: Please share the error message you are getting. Also, try deleting the database and then creating a new database. It often works.